# How do I require a keyof to be for a property of a specific type?

Tags: typescript

I am attempting to write a generic function that can toggle a boolean property in any object by key name. I read the [release notes for TypeScript-2.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) and thought that conditional types are supposed to solve this type of issue. However, I cannot figure out how to write my function.

My function accepts the object to be modified and the name of the key to modify. To ensure that only keys for boolean properties are passed in, I used the conditional type expression `T[K] extends boolean ? K : never`. As I understand it, this should cause an error if I try to pass a key for a non-boolean property because `T[K]` would not satisfy `extends boolean`. But if I tried to pass a key for a boolean, then it should accept that `K`.

However, it seems that even with this conditional, TypeScript does not realize within the function that `T[K] extends boolean` must be true. So I can’t assign the value I read from the object back to the object. This results in the first error shown below. The second error is that type inference doesn’t seem to work for my function. In the calls below, only the second one passes TypeScript’s checks so far.

```
function invertProperty<T, K extends keyof T> (o:T, propertyName:(T[K] extends boolean ? K : never)) {
  o[propertyName] = !o[propertyName]; // Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'T[T[K] extends boolean ? K : never]'. [2322]
}

const myObject:IObject = {
  a: 1,
  b: true,
  c: 'hi',
};

invertProperty(myObject, 'b'); // Argument of type '"b"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. [2345]
invertProperty<IObject, 'b'>(myObject, 'b'); // Works, but requires me to type too much.
invertProperty(myObject, 'a'); // Argument of type '"a"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. [2345]
invertProperty<IObject, 'a'>(myObject, 'a'); // Argument of type '"a"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. [2345]

interface IObject {
  a:number,
  b:boolean,
  c:string,
}
```

I think that if in my type constraint of `K extends keyof T` I could somehow also state `and T[K] extends boolean` it would do the right thing. It seems to me that it is an issue that I’m trying to use `never` in the argument’s type instead of being able to constrain the type parameter. But I can’t find any way to express that.

Any ideas of how to accomplish this with full type safety?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, you can extract all keys of boolean properties using this construct (which converts keys of non-boolean values to `never` and takes a union of all keys/never, using fact that `T | never` is `T`):

```
type BooleanKeys<T> = { [k in keyof T]: T[k] extends boolean ? k : never }[keyof T];
```

Then, to make TypeScript happy about assigning boolean values to properties, you introduce intermediate type which is declared to have only boolean properties (unfortunately TypeScript cannot figure out this part on its own)

```
type OnlyBoolean<T> = { [k in BooleanKeys<T>]: boolean };
```

and you declare that generic type parameter of `invertProperty` is compatible with `OnlyBoolean` (which it is, it may contain extra non-boolean properties but it's OK)

**NOTE** you might need different versions of the code depending of the version of the compiler, original code in this answer has stopped working with TypeScript 3.2:

```
// for TypeScript 3.1 or earlier
function invertProperty<T extends OnlyBoolean<T>>(o: T, propertyName: BooleanKeys<T>) {
    o[propertyName] = !o[propertyName];
}

// for TypeScript 3.2 or later
function invertProperty<T>(o: OnlyBoolean<T>, propertyName: keyof OnlyBoolean<T>) {
    o[propertyName] = !o[propertyName];
}


interface IObject {
    a: number;
    b: boolean;
    c: string;
}
const myObject:IObject = {
  a: 1,
  b: true,
  c: 'hi',
};



invertProperty(myObject, 'b'); // ok
invertProperty(myObject, 'a'); // error
```

Comment: I tried this in the Typescript playground but it's shows a compiler error on the assignment of o[propertyName]=!o[propertyName] saying 
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'T[{ [k in keyof T]: T[k] extends boolean ? k : never; }[keyof T]]'.
Stackblitz typescript project does not show the error. My local typescript compiler (3.2.2) also gives the same error

Comment: I updated the answer, 3.1 was the last version for which the original code was working. The compiler is changing, the original code was not strictly type safe according to the rules in effect in 3.2.

Comment: This actually does a dangerous coercion: any type that is assignable to the "target" type (boolean, in this case) is treated as the target type.  Modify your code so that the type of `IObject#b` is `true` instead of `boolean` and it still compiles without any warnings.  [My similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64449138/26286) explores other approaches.

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on @artem's answer (I'd make it a comment if code were readable in comments), you can use generics to generalise the `type` further to allow using the trick for properties of any type on any type.

```js
type PropsCoercedToPOrNeverOnO<O, P> = { [k in keyof O]: O[k] extends P ? k : never }[keyof O];
export type PropsOfTypePOnO<P, O> = { [k in PropsCoercedToPOrNeverOnO<P, O>]: O };

interface IObject {
  a: number;
  b: boolean;
  c: string;
}

function dynamicallyUpdateProperty(
  o: IObject,
  propKey: keyof PropsOfTypePOnO<IObject, string>,
  newValue: string,
) {
  o[propKey] = newValue;
}

const myObject: IObject = {
  a: 1,
  b: true,
  c: 'hi',
};

dynamicallyUpdateProperty(myObject, 'a', 'world') // type error
dynamicallyUpdateProperty(myObject, 'sdfds', 'world') // type error
dynamicallyUpdateProperty(myObject, 'c', 'world') // compiles
```

I don't experience the danger @Coderer describes - if I constrain `c: 'foo' | 'bar'` on `IObject` then `dynamicallyUpdateProperty` stops compiling unless I change `newValue` to have type `'foo' | 'bar'` as well.

Strangely I can't genericise the `dynamicallyUpdateProperty` function further. I'd expect the following to work:

```js
function dynamicallyUpdateProperty<O, P>(
  o: O,
  propKey: keyof PropsOfTypePOnO<O, P>,
  newValue: P,
) {
  o[propKey] = newValue; // compile error - TS2322: Type 'P' is not assignable to type 'O[PropsOfTypePOrNeverOnO ]'.
}
```

But it doesn't, error shown above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mapped types to narrow the properties of an existing type to only those of type boolean and then use `keyof`. [TS Documentation on Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

You can achieve this with the following code:

```js
const invert = <T>(entity: T, key: keyof PickProperties<T, boolean>): void => {
    entity[key] = !entity[key] as any;
    // when removing the any cast you get a compile error:
    // Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof PickProperties<T, boolean>]'.
}

type PickProperties<T, TFilter> = { [K in keyof T as (T[K] extends TFilter ? K : never)]: T[K] }
```

The only drawback is the `any` inside the `invert` function. It works from the callers perspective though.

Example on how to use this:

```js
const func = () => {
    const myInterface: MyInterface = {
        foo: '',
        bar: true,
        baz: 3
    };

    console.log(myInterface.bar); // true

    invert(myInterface, 'bar');

    console.log(myInterface.bar); // false

    // invert(myInterface, 'foo'); // error
    // Argument of type '"foo"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"bar"'.
}

interface MyInterface {
    foo: string;
    bar: boolean;
    baz: number;
}
```