# Generic sort function with T[K] constraints

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm learning TypeScript and currently, I'm trying to create a generic sort function.

I have two interfaces:

```
interface RefreshToken {
  client_icon?: string;
  client_id?: string;
  client_name?: string;
  created_at?: string;
  id?: string;
  is_current?: boolean;
  last_used_at?: string;
  last_used_ip?: string;
  type: "normal" | "long_lived_access_token";
}

interface PersistentNotification {
  created_at: string;
  message?: string;
  notification_id?: string;
  title: string;
  status?: "read" | "unread";
}
```

And my current function looks like so:

```
function SortByDateAscending<T, K extends keyof T>(values: T[], key: K) {
  const compare = (first: T, second: T) => {
    const timeA = first[key] ? new Date(first[key]) : 0;
    const timeB = second[key] ? new Date(second[key]) : 0;
    if (timeA < timeB) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (timeA > timeB) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  };
  return values.sort(compare);
}
```

the above code works, but I get warnings:

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 5, '(value: string |
> number | Date): Date', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'T[K]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | Date'.
> Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | Date'.
> Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | Date'.
> Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | Date'.
> Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
> Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
> Type 'T[K]' is not assignable to type 'Date'.

Not sure if there is a way to add a constraint that will tell that `T[K]` must be `string | number | Date`

Here is my test project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-yzualr
I currently passing only string types (one is optional), but will also use Date, so if T[K] is Date I shouldn't use `new Date`.

I'd like to avoid any changes to interfaces and of course creating separate functions per type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I require a keyof to be for a property of a specific type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50851263/how-do-i-require-a-keyof-to-be-for-a-property-of-a-specific-type)

Answer (score 1):

You could pass your sort method a method instead of a key name

```js
function sortByDateAscending<T>(
   values: T[], getDate: (val: T) => string | number | Date) {
   // ...
}

tokens = sortByDateAscending(tokens, token => token.last_used_at);
```

Comment: I think some brackets are missing around `getDate`

Comment: No, there are no brackets missing. I've copied it to the playground and it works [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgJygIQJ4BECGUApgILIRFgAmMYA5gDwAqAfABQBQi3AbvgDYgiyAFyImAbQC6AGkR0iUAsTFs+-MUwCUiALwsUUNLTqIAPojAgAtgCMiac4mVEdAby7cA9F8QA6AM9ENEUQNCR1IWQ-VAw2Nh19RAAGLQ4AXw4OfkVEKDgAa0pkPUQJN0R+fGQoAH0QZCIqWsIxAHJgODg2xHSpDnyisBLdFHQsPEJSckoaejZB4rlFpCSVvyqa+sbmwi0AbiA)